# How to select the rows in one table that are not in another table using mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

This is a part of my query. The following query returns the rows that are found as shown below:

`ref = Google`
and the `hash is found` on the `elements_actions` table.

However, I want to get the rows that:
`ref = Google` but for now, the `hash is NOT found` into the `elements_actions` table.

For example if 
all from Google are 100 and the following query returns 60, out of a `new_table` 200 rows, that means the opposite must return 40.

I tried with `elements_actions.hash != new_table.hash` without any luck.

```
FROM behaviour, new_table, elements_actions
                WHERE 
                     behaviour.ref = 'Google' 
                     AND elements_actions.hash = new_table.hash 
                     AND elements_actions.element_id = 3
```

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk -> MariaDB then input/desired output. Code sample shows more than words.

Comment: BTW - you may want to look into using the newer sql standards for join syntax. Yours are in the where clause, which works, but putting joins in the from clause make queries like this so much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most straight-forward way is to literally ask the DB which ones don't exist in that table using "NOT EXISTS"

```
FROM behaviour, new_table
WHERE 
 behaviour.ref = 'Google' 
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM elements_actions WHERE elements_actions.hash = new_table.hash AND elements_actions.element_id = 3)
```

You could also use a left outer join on elements_actions.hash = new_table.hash and then check for "new_table.hash is null" in your WHERE clause.

Comment: the "not exists" doesnt return any rows.. can you help me with a left outer join example ?

Comment: I'd prefer to figure out why the NOT EXISTS doesn't work for you first. Have I misunderstood your requirement... are you trying to get data from elements_action where the hash doesn't exist in new_table, or are you trying to get data from new_table where the hash doesn't exist in elements_action?

Comment: the second is the answer. i am trying to find hash from the new_table that do not exist in elements_actions.

Comment: Okay, my mistake, I wrote the above backwards. Does new_table also have a element_id that needs to be 3, or you're just getting them all if they don't have a hash in elements_actions? I'll fix my answer once I know that.

Comment: I have edited my answer to (hopefully) do wha you want now.

Comment: the new_table has no the element_id

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a left outer join. Your posting doesn't show the join between behaviour and elements_actions so you need to add that.

```
 FROM behaviour
      JOIN elements_actions ON ([[you need to provide the join columns here between behavior and elements_actions]])
      LEFT OUTER JOIN new_table ON (elemtns_actions.hash = net_table.hash)
WHERE behaviour.ref = 'Google' 
  AND elements_actions.element_id = 3 
  AND new_table.hash IS NULL
```

A left outer join returns all the values from an inner join plus all values in the left table that do not match to the right table, including rows with NULL (empty) values in the link column.

This Wikipedia entry has lots of good info about join types but it can get overbearing with the math. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join